# How to route new leads to a back up sales rep temporarily if the actual rep is on leave?

Tags: leads, assignment-rules

This is more of an admin question.

We are using [round robin process](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004000) to assign web leads to our sales rep but if 'Sales Rep A' goes on vacation and I need to assign all the leads coming to 'Sales Rep A' from round robin flow to 'Sales Rep B' temporarily and once 'Sales Rep A' is back from vacation I should be able to remove this temporary configuration.

Is there any out of box thing that I can use in Salesforce or do you guys recommend any workaround without touching the actual round robin process??

Comment: Do you have it set up the way documented where you are assigning to queues or are you assigning directly to users?

Comment: @cricketlang Directly to users instead of queues.

Comment: And I'm assuming you are looking for a solution other than just changing the assignment value to another user manually? Is this a one time thing or are you looking for something that may be scalable going forward?

Comment: Yes, I do not want to change the actual assignment rules. I am looking for more of a solution where the lead goes to the actual sales rep as per the round robin and then based on our workaround it reassigns that lead to another rep. This is not a one time thing and we might need to do this more frequently as we have 20 sales reps.

Comment: Where do you track if one of your users is "not in the office"? So if you were to fire the reassignment event of of something, what would that something be in Salesforce?

Comment: I get a ticket in Zendesk saying that John is going on leave and assign his future leads to James with start and end date from our sales director.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't necessarily say this is the best process but I have certainly seen this done (when OWD for Leads is not `private`)

- Keep your lead assignment as is
- For the sales rep X covering their own + the rep Y on leave's Leads ... create a custom List View, report, or dashboard that includes both the Leads owned by rep X plus the leads owned by rep Y.
- Have rep X use the new list view/report/dashboard to work their leads

This works because normally the reps are human beings and used to covering for each other as 'covering' is a fact of life in the work world

Comment: I'll support this too because after I finished breakfast, it dawned on me that you wouldn't really want to give the leads to someone else because the owner is on vacation, I would just want someone to cover anything that needed to be immediately actionable.

Comment: I think this may not work as usually the OWD is set to private for leads for sales reps.

Comment: @javanoob - good point, I amended my answer. One could argue that OWD private is overkill as sales reps can see their leads easily with 'My Leads' views/reports and frankly, because of the 'covering' aspect of the real world, making Leads private seems a bit coercive.